# If $F$ is a field with $\operatorname{char} F = 0$ and $f(x) \in F[x]$ irreducible, all zeros of $f(x)$ in any extension has multiplicity $s = 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

What I have trying is:

Suppose that $f(x)$ has at least one zero $\alpha$ such that $f(x) = (x - \alpha)^sq(x)$, $s > 1$ in some extension. Then I guess that $(x-\alpha)^{s-1} \mid f(x)$.
So, $f(x)$ is not irreducible, where $f(x) = (x-a)^{s-1}h(x)$.
But is seems wrong once I neither used the hypothesis $\operatorname{char} F = 0$.

What I am loosing? Could someone help me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outline: We can assume that $f$ has degree $n\gt 1$. Then $f'(x)$ has degree $n-1$. (This is where we use characteristic $0$. In characteristic $p$, this part can fail. For example, the derivative of $x^p+1$ is the $0$ polynomial.)

Since $f$ is irreducible, $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are relatively prime over $F$. By the Bezout Identity, they are relatively prime over any extension field $K$ of $f$. But then $f(x)$ cannot have a root of multiplicity $\gt 1$ over $K$, since if $(x-a)^2$ divides $f(x)$ over $K$, then $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are not relatively prime over $K$: each is divisible by $x-a$.

Comment: why $f$ irreducible implies that $gcd(f,f') = 1?$

Comment: what is $p(x)$?

Comment: The $p(x)$ was a typo for $f(x)$.  If the gcd were greater than $1$, it would have positive degree $\le \text{deg}(f)-1$, because that's the degree of $f'(x)$. So $f(x)$ would have a proper divisor, contradicting irreducibility.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite right, first of all $(x-\alpha)^{s-1}$ might not be a polynomial with coefficients in $F$ when $\alpha\not\in F$. However, you do know in characteristic $0$ that the derivative of a non-constant polynomial is not $0$. If

$$f(x)=(x-\alpha)^s\prod_{i=1}^n (x-\alpha_i)^{e_j}, s>1, e_j\ge 1$$

then we have that $\gcd(f'(x),f(x))$--both of which have coefficients in $F$--cannot be $1$, since this same relationship would hold in an extension where clearly $(x-\alpha)\big|\gcd(f(x),f'(x))$, i.e. $\alpha$ is a root of this gcd, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Does your proof is: Once $f$ and $f'$ are not non-zero, suppose $\alpha$ is a zero such that its multiplicity be $s > 1$. Then $(x-\alpha) | gcd(f(x),f'(x))$, and then, $\alpha$ is a zero of $gcd(f(x),f'(x)) \neq 1$ what contradict the hypothesis of $f(x)$ be irreducible. Is this?

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're asking, but it seems like you've correctly rephrased my proof.